# Getting user info after authenticated with Linkedin Oauth using php

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

1) I downloaded the files from [here](https://github.com/mahmudahsan/Linkedin---Simple-%20%20integration-for-your-website)

2) Created the linkedin app where I added website URL as `http://localhost`

(I am doing it at localhost) and redirect URI as `http://localhost/demo/demo.php`

3) Inserted API key and secret key generated after creating the LinkedIn app

in `auth.php` and `demo.php` as below:

```
$config['base_url']             =   'http://localhost/demo/auth.php';
$config['callback_url']         =   'http://localhost/demo/demo.php';
$config['linkedin_access']      =   'XXXXXXXXApi_keyXXXXXXX';
$config['linkedin_secret']      =   'XXXXXXXXsecret_keyXXXXXXX';
```

when I click on the link like `http:// localhost/demo/auth.php` it redirects to

`https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=` and here I receive an error that says:

```
"An Error occurred during authorization, please try again later."
```

Kindly let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you register your App with LinkedIn??

Comment: yes I did register my App with linkedin, only then I can have API key and secret. isn't it or I need to do something else please let me know.

Comment: Well I am in the exact same position. It would be nice to know if and how did you solved this issue?

Comment: Have you got any answer to your issue..i am also facing same issue..Please help.Thanks